# display udf returned array in excel

Tags: sql, arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am creating a UDF which will return a 2D array of variant/string. I want to display this returned array nicely in excel with the top left corner element of the array shown in the cell where UDF function was entered.

basically my function is like:

```
Function func(sql as String)

    Dim Password As String
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Database_Name As String

    Server_Name = "XXXXXXXX"
    Database_Name = "YYYYYY"
    User_ID = "zzzzzz"
    Password = "vvvvvvvvv"

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

     cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=" & _
       Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
       ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
     rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic

     result = rs.GetRows()
     function_caller = Application.Caller.Address

     If VarType(result) = 8204 Then
        For r = 0 To UBound(result, 1)
           For c = 0 To UBound(result, 2)
             Range(function_caller).Offset(r, c).Value = result(r, c)
           Next
        Next
     End If

End Function
```

when I type in cell C10 the following formula

```
=func("select * from db.sample_table")
```

assuming running the SQL returns me an array with 5 rows 6 columns, I hope the array can be nicely displayed in the range C10:H14. When I mouse click on C10，I will be able to see my formula.

I know UDF returned value cannot be written into any cell other than the cell where udf was called. Because of this, I tried to populate my array into cells before the UDF finish executing. However, the above code will only display a "0" in C10 cell.

Comment: currently the above code will show #VALUE！ error in the cell where the function is entered.

Comment: Why use a UDF for that, Excel already allows you to get data from a database using tools form the Data tab?

Comment: hi jkpieterse, thanks for getting back. I am aware of that. the sql is just for illustration. in actual implementation, the udf will take in different values and assemble the sql in code. This code is suppose to help user who doesn't know who to write sql to extract data.

Comment: You are also aware you can place parameters in cells to drive an automatic refresh using different filter values directly in the cell? Getting data from a database using a UDF will make your calculation potentially very slow.

Comment: unfortunately the data has to be taken from the database. Because the entire database is 30+ gigabytes, which is too big to be handled by excel. compromise on speed is unavoidable I guess.

Comment: UDF does not allow changing any other cell values. Use PowerPivot for datasets Excel cannot handle.

Comment: so far the main issue I face is the variable function_caller.  I want to display my array starting from the cell where UDF is put in. If I relax this constraint and put a random fixed cell like C10 such as

    Range("C10“).Offset(r, c).Value = result(r, c)

the array gets printed out nicely starting from the hardcoded C10 cell.

Comment: I know the data has to be taken from a database. I just think you're trying to solve this using the wrong tool (VBA). Use a database query or powerquery to fetch your data into a (pivot)table. Both have methods to draw the criteria from cell values.

Comment: This will not work the way you want as a UDF called from a worksheet cell because a UDF can only return values to its calling cells. So you would have to array enter the UDF into multiple cells and return an array rather than individual cells: but you don't know how many cells to use.

Comment: would be possible that I write my array directly into the cells within the function, then only return the upper left corner element of my array as one single data point?